# Having MS Access Search Outlook for e-mails

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

So I am trying to create a Macro that will search my e-mails based on a piece of information on an access form  I know I am close but I cannot seem to figure out the final piece

```
Private Sub btnEMAIL_Click()

    Dim strID As String, strMessages As String
    Call Outlook_open 'CHECKS TO SEE IF OUT LOOK IS OPEN

    Dim myOlApp As Object
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'Creates outlook object

    strID = PayeeID.Value 'this is a value on the form
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myitems As Outlook.Items

    Dim myitem As Object
    Dim blnfound As Boolean

    Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.Folders("HQP Field Compensation").Folders("Inbox")
    Set myitems = myInbox.Items

    Set mySearch = AdvancedSearch(Scope:=myInbox,Filter:="urn:schemas:mailheader:subject= '" & strID & "'")
    Set myResults = mySearch.Results

    If myResults.Count > 0 Then

        For intCounter = 1 To myResults.Count
            myResults.Item(intCounter).Display 'Should display the relevant e-mail
        Next intCounter
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

AdvancedSearch is asynchronous/ Since you are only searching through the Inbox, use Items.Restrict or Items.Find/FindNext

```
set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
set myItems = myInbox.Items
set myItem = myItems.Find("[Subject]='" & strID & "'")
while Not (myItem Is Nothing)
  myItem.Display
  set myItem = myItems.FindNext
wend
```

Comment: It does not work because strID is not the exact name.  It is just in the subject.

Comment: Try a query like `"@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F"" LIKE '%" & stride & "%'"`.